# What is the meaning of the Hebrew word Israel - Struggle or Prince? Any scholarly resources on this? cf. Genesis 32:28

Tags: hebrew, genesis, israel, etymology

The Hebrew word Israel gets translated Struggle and Prince i.e. Gen 32:28. Are there any good scholarly resources that can help clarify which meaning is more accurate?

Comment: See [Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_(name)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names Israel is יִשְׂרָאֵל from two other words: from sarah and el, that is:

- שָׂרָה (sarah) = verb persist, exert oneself, persevere (BDB), and
- אֵל (el) = god or God, etc, (BDB).

Thus, יִשְׂרָאֵל is "God strives/struggles" or "strives/struggles with God".  Of these two the latter appears to be the origin of the proper name as per Gen 32:28 -

> Then the man said, “Your name will no longer be Jacob, but Israel,
> because you have struggled with God and with men, and you have
> prevailed.”

However, the "prince" aspect cannot be ignored as the second part of the word may be derived from the Hebrew "sar" = "prince".  As with many Hebrew words and names, multiple levels of meaning are usually intended.  For example, note the comments in Gen 35:10 -

> And God said to him, “Though your name is Jacob,f you will no longer
> be called Jacob. Instead, your name will be Israel.g” So God named him
> Israel.  And God told him, “I am God Almighty.h Be fruitful and
> multiply. A nation—even a company of nations—shall come from you, and
> kings shall descend from you.

The Cambridge commentary observes the same thing (Gen 32:28) -

> 28. Israel] That is, He who striveth with God, or, God striveth. The name is clearly a title of victory, from a root meaning “to
>     persevere.” (a) The meaning seems here to be applied to Jacob as “the
>     perseverer with God.” It is commonly compared with Jerubbaal = “he
>     that striveth with Baal” (Jdg 6:32). The prophet Hosea gives this
>     meaning in Genesis 12:3-4, “in his manhood [or ‘strength’] he had
>     power [or ‘persevered,’ ‘strove’] with God; yea, he had power over the
>     angel, and prevailed.” (b) The meaning, on the analogy of similarly
>     formed words, would be “El persevereth”; and would be exactly similar
>     to Seraiah = “Jah perseveres”; Ishmael = “God hears.” Another
>     suggested derivation is from sar = “prince.” See another account of
>     the origin of the name “Israel” given by P in Genesis 35:10.

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 32:28
New International Version

> Then the man said, "Your name will no longer be Jacob, but Israel, because you have **struggled with God** and with humans and have overcome."

you have struggled
שָׂרִ֧יתָ (śā·rî·ṯā)
Verb - Qal - Perfect - second person masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 8280: To **persist**, exert oneself, persevere

God
אֱלֹהִ֛ים (’ĕ·lō·hîm)
Noun - masculine plural
Strong's Hebrew 430: gods -- the supreme **God**, magistrates, a superlative

https://biblehub.com/hebrew/3478.htm

NAS Exhaustive Concordance

> Word Origin
> from **sarah** and **el**
> Definition
> "**God strives**," another name of Jacob and his desc.

Strong's Concordance

> sarah: to persist, exert oneself, persevere
> Original Word: שָׂרָה
> Part of Speech: Verb
> Transliteration: sarah
> Phonetic Spelling: (saw-raw')
> Definition: to **persist**, exert oneself, persevere

Strong's Concordance

> el: **God**, in pl. gods
> Original Word: אֵל
> Part of Speech: Noun Masculine
> Transliteration: el
> Phonetic Spelling: (ale)
> Definition: God, in pl. gods

Answer (score 0):

1. "Yisrael" (יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל) - **Meaning** :

> "Since You-Wrestled With-God" (כִּֽי־שָׂרִ֧יתָ עִם־אֱלֹהִ֛ים)

2. **YiSRaEL (יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל)** is an Acronym formed from letters taken from its Meaning (כִּֽי־שָׂרִ֧יתָ עִם־אֱלֹהִ֛ים) :

- K**i** (כִּֽי) provides the [Yod].
- **Sar**it (שָׂרִ֧יתָ) provides the [Shin + Reish].
- Im-**El**ohim (עִם־אֱלֹהִ֛ים) provides the [Alef + Lamed].

As an Acronym, YiSRaEL (יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל) defines itself (כִּֽי־שָׂרִ֧יתָ עִם־אֱלֹהִ֛ים).